# Live notifications with jQuery

Tags: jquery, notifications, real-time

I have this code:

```
    $(window).load(function(){
setInterval(function(){
var username=_userdata['username'];
var username=_userdata['username'];
$.get('/notification.forum',function(data){
     var b= data.unread;
    if(b >= 1){
      var c = data.store;
      for(var keys in c){
        var d = c[keys];
       if(d.read === 0){
        var e= d.text.type;
        var from= d.text.from.name;
        var topic = e===7 ? "in the topic "+d.text.post.topic_name.replace(/-/g,' ') : "";
        var type= Notify(e);
          createNotifcation('http://i.imgur.com/LPVUvcf.png',username + ' you have a new notification!',type + " from "+from+"  "+topic);
       }
      }
     }
   });
},5000);
   });
```

But i want to make it in real time. It's checking every 5 seconds, but this makes my forum giving errors, like Request limit exceeded.. and well, this is annoying.
My forum: www.daily-support.org

Comment: For ongoing updates, your options are AJAX polling (which is what you're doing now) and Web Sockets (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets).